# CSS Transition not working on class toggle JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, sass, fade

Hello this is probably something easy and dumb, but I am not understanding why my css transition is not working on class toggle/remove/add function from JavaScript. I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of css transitions and vanilla JS... I added a codepen. 
https://codepen.io/skwisgaar/pen/Yzygvqz

The class is added and removed as needed, but the transition is sharp with the transition in my css ignored. I don't think it's a problem with my css, I added a hover to test the transition without the add/remove in JS. It seems like this is the default behavior for JS? Is there something I need to add for the transition to work before or when the class is changed in JS? Any help is appreciated.

```
  const btn = document.querySelector('#show-hide');
  const pagenav = document.querySelector('#page-nav');
  const showhide = () => {
    if(pagenav.classList.contains('hidden')){
      pagenav.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      pagenav.classList.add('hidden');
    } 
  }
  btn.onclick = showhide;
```

Here is my css:

```
#page-nav {
    opacity:1;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    @include transition(opacity 500ms);
    &.hidden {
        opacity:0;
    }
    &:hover {
      opacity:0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conflicting style for the class "hidden".

[image: CSS definition for hidden]

When the hidden class is applied it is set to display: none so it is essentially not included in the page layout and so cannot transition other properties.

Comment: Holy crap. haha I been working too long. I looked in the tailwind docs and didn't see the class or probably just zoned it out. Ended up doing the same thing in my project and my code pen. Figured it was something dumb smh.Thnx man, thought I was going crazy here, I really appreciate it! T__T